# Get input from dynamically created input

Tags: python, tkinter

How would I retrieve input if I created a bunch of input boxes like this

```
expensefields=[]
expenses = [i for i in range(6)]
count=0
for expense in expenses:

    expense = Entry(master)
    expense.grid(row=count,column=2)
    expenseinputs.append(expense)
    count=count+1
```

I know about using the `.get()` method, but not sure how to approach this. If I'm doing this the wrong way I'd love to get some pointers.

Comment: What have you implemented so far to get the input? Your code only shows the set up.

Comment: @Idlehands I edited my code. I store each entry field in a list and access it by using `expensefields[0].get()` for example

Comment: The updated code still shows the same premise and raises even more questions.  Nowhere is `expensefields` referenced beside the empty `list` assignment and yet you access it somehow.  Is `expenseinputs` meant to be `expensefields`?   Please provide a [MCVE] that shows *all* the relevant parts of your attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem earlier, and after lots of searching i kind of figured it out. There might be better answers though so i will love to hear better answers too.

For you to use the `get()` method, you need to store the widget somewhere, say a list.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
expenses = [i for i in range(6)]
count=0
widget = []
for expense in expenses:
    expense = tk.Entry(root)
    expense.grid(row=count,column=2)
    expense.insert(0,"{}".format(count))
    count=count+1
    widget.append(expense)

print (widget[2].get())

root.mainloop()
```

Now you can use `get()` on the widgets by passing an index to the list.

Comment: Haha I tried it this way right before I saw your answer. If nobody else has a better answer I'll accept this one. Thanks.